# Structuring Left Float Image with Two Text Boxes

Tags: html, css

having a few problems with formatting this website (just learning html css!)

Issues I can't solve:

1) top image is centered but the rest are left

2) image icon size is too large and pushes text to bottom level

3) text at the bottom won't start on a new line

Site is yodega.com/sell

```css
html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, ul, ol, li, p, a {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  color: #FAD48B;
  margin: 15px 0 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
h2 {
  color: #FAD48B;
  margin: 20px 0 5px 0;
  padding: 2px;
   
}
h3 {
  color: #FAD48B;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    
}


//removes top nav
.nav{
    display: none;
}
//attepmt to fix header to top
.header{
    position: fixed;
}

.benefit-icon img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.benefit-icon{
    top-margin:5px;
    width:20%;
    height:125px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left;
}

.benefit-title{
    width:80%;
    height:35px;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    font-size:25px;
    font-decoration:bold;
}

.intro-space{
    bottom-margin:10px;
    float:left;
}

.benefit-detail{
    width:80%;
    height:25px;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:70px;
    font-size:15px;
}

.sell-title{
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-size:55px;
    padding-bottom:40px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height: 55px;
}

.astericks{
    margin-top:5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 692pxpx)   {
    .main, .small{
        width:100%;   
        float:none;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<div class="sell-title">Sell with Yodega</div>

<div class="intro-space"> </div>

<div class="benefit-icon"></div>
<img src="/images/blankClock.png">
<div class="benefit-title blue">
<div class="benefit-title blue">Fast &amp; Easy Set Up – Start Selling Today</div>
</div>
<div class="benefit-detail purple">
<div class="benefit-detail purple">store complete in 10 minutes with no programming required</div>
</div>

<div class="benefit-icon"></div>
<img src="/images/blankClock.png">
<div class="benefit-title blue">
<div class="benefit-title blue">Zero Set Up Cost: free Store &amp; Listings</div>
</div>
<div class="benefit-detail purple">
<div class="benefit-detail purple">keep more of your money – only very small selling fees*</div>
</div>
<div class="benefit-icon"></div>
<img src="/images/blankClock.png">
<div class="benefit-title orange">Your Own Personal Store – Custom URL &amp; Store</div>
<div class="benefit-detail green">your own store page with direct web link</div>
<div class="benefit-icon"></div>
<img src="/images/blankClock.png">
<div class="benefit-title blue">No fee for store or listings</div>
<div class="benefit-detail purple">only small 4.9% + typical credit card processing</div>
<div class="benefit-icon"></div>
<img src="/images/blankClock.png">
<div class="benefit-title orange">Hassle-free selling</div>
<div class="benefit-detail green">Yodega takes care of everything – you just sell and ship</div>
<div class="benefit-icon"></div>
<img src="/images/blankClock.png">
<div class="benefit-title blue">Reduce your fee rate with referrals</div>
<div class="benefit-detail purple">eeach seller you refer*permanently* reduces your fee rate**</div>
<div class="benefit-icon"></div>
<img src="/images/blankClock.png">
<div class="benefit-title blue">Seller Dashboard Makes Managing Easy</div>
<div class="benefit-detail purple">customized sales reports and orders page</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div>

<div class="astericks">*4.9% + typical credit card processing fees
**A vaild referral requires a recommendation within 1 month of referral store opening. Store must sell $300 of sales before referral rate reduction activates. Maximium .9% in reduction from standard fee rate from referral incentives.</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so there are a lot of things that can be changed.

One would be remove the "p" tags from around your images and place them inside of the benefit-icon div.

Another remove the height, and play with the margins for your text divs and add a clear all or both after each group.

You can fix a lot of these issues easily, just look at your code structure. Your img should be in its wrapper not a paragraph tag.

These might not be the proper way to handle your issues, be sure to some research on basic website formatting.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow, can't believe I had the images outside of the div. Thanks!

Comment: @jacobJordan also remove the p tags. p stands for paragraph not picture if that is what you where thinking. https://devdocs.io/html/element/p

Comment: appreciate it - the p was actually unrelated (I'm working in a child theme so that's more of a general setting - included it all in case there was some unintended consequences from that).

Much, much appreciate your help. You solved 2 hours of me searching in no time!